# Add Spinner as Tab item using design support library

Tags: android, android-tablayout, androiddesignsupport

I am using Design support library to create Tabs. I added Toolbar and Tab view layout.

I want to add Spinner widget as one of the TAB with design support library.

Is it possible to add Spinner as one of the TAB item? Can you give example?

```html
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/flContent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/layout_drawer_header"
        app:itemTextColor="#000000"
        app:menu="@menu/global"></android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

```html
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    CoordinatorLayout rootLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
        initToolbar();
        //getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, new LettersFragment()).commit();
        rootLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.rootLayout);
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.string.opendrawer,
                R.string.closedrawer);
        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
        if (navigationView != null) {
            setupDrawerContent(navigationView);
        }

        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

                switch (tab.getPosition()) {
                    case 0:
                        showToast("One");
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        showToast("Three");

                        break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
    }

    void showToast(String msg) {
        Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFrag(new DummyFragment(getResources().getColor(R.color.accent_material_light)), "ENGLISH");
        adapter.addFrag(new DummyFragment(getResources().getColor(R.color.ripple_material_light)), "TELUGU");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.newTab();
        Spinner spinner = new Spinner(MainActivity.this);
//        spinner.setAdapter(new SimpleAdapter());
        tab.setCustomView(spinner);
        tabLayout.addTab(tab);
```

Comment: I updated my post. I am not able to set "setCustomView". Please see above code and help me.

Comment: Change tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager); to addTab one by one.